# Rails::Application::RoutesReloader error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to migrate tables. using rake db:migrate.. but my command prompt shows me following error..please anyone help me...with this... 
using rails 4.0.0.
my command prompt shows this:

```
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future.
If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_av
ailable_locales = false to avoid this message.
rake aborted!
Rails::Application::RoutesReloader#execute_if_updated delegated to updater.execu
te_if_updated, but updater is nil: #<Rails::Application::RoutesReloader:0x5b5eee
0 @paths=["C:/Sites/project/config/routes.rb"], @route_sets=[#<ActionDispatch::R
outing::RouteSet:0x5bf73d0>]>
C:3:in `rescue in execute_if_updated'
C:131071:in `execute_if_updated'
C:/Sites/project/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

my routes.rb :

```
Project::Application.routes.draw do


resources :studentregs
resources :subjects

resources :posts do
resources :comments, :only => [:create]
member { post :vote }
end


devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
get 'tags/:tag', to: 'posts#index', as: :tag

get "teacherregs/new"
get "teacherregs/create"
get "teacherregs/show"
get "teacherregs/index"
get "teacherregs/edit"
get "teacherregs/update"
get "teacherregs/destroy"

get "posts/create"
get "posts/destroy"
get "posts/new"
get "posts/index"
get "posts/show"
get "posts/edit"
get "posts/update"
get "studentregs/new"
get "studentregs/create"
get "studentregs/show"
get "studentregs/index"
get "studentregs/edit"
get "studentregs/update"
get "studentregs/destroy"
devise_for :cubeprincipals
devise_for :cubestudents
devise_for :cubeteachers
get "home", :to => "pages#home" 
get "about" ,:to => "pages#about" 
get "help" ,:to => "pages#help" 
get "contactus", :to => "pages#contactus" 



root to: 'pages#home'
# The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
# See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

# You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
# root 'welcome#index'

# Example of regular route:
#   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

# Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
#   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

# Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
#   resources :products

# Example resource route with options:
#   resources :products do
#     member do
#       get 'short'
#       post 'toggle'
#     end

#     collection do
#       get 'sold'
#     end
#   end

# Example resource route with sub-resources:
#   resources :products do
#     resources :comments, :sales
#     resource :seller
#   end

# Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
#   resources :products do
#     resources :comments
#     resources :sales do
#       get 'recent', on: :collection
#     end
#   end

# Example resource route with concerns:
#   concern :toggleable do
#     post 'toggle'
#   end
#   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
#   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

# Example resource route within a namespace:
#   namespace :admin do
#     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
#     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
#     resources :products
#   end  
end
```

Comment: Perhaps you could try `Rails.application.reload_routes!` ?

Comment: Thank you Rich... but it is still showing me the same error...

Comment: :( Thanks for reply! Do you want me to refactor your routes? I think you need to improve your structure

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment, here's a revised `routes.rb` for you. Don't know if it will help directly, but should ensure some issues are fixed:

```
Project::Application.routes.draw do

   resources :studentregs, :subjects, :teacherregs, :posts, :studentregs
   pages = %w(home about contactus help)
   for page in pages do
        get page, to: "pages##{page}"
   end

   resources :posts do
      resources :comments, :only => [:create]
      member { post :vote }
   end

   devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
   ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
   get 'tags/:tag', to: 'posts#index', as: :tag


   devise_for :cubeprincipals
   devise_for :cubestudents
   devise_for :cubeteachers    

   root to: 'pages#home'

end
```

You had a lot of routes using `get` requests. Although this might be simpler, it goes against [RESTful routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) convention & should be avoided

Hopefully this clears up any problems your routes file may have had